# Can't get Text with Find Element by xpath with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to get all the text from the element '`show-more-less-html__markup`' from the example below with selenium and Python:

[image]

This is my try :

```
description = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='show-more-less-html__markup']").text
```

Comment: Are you trying to get all the texts inside that element or some specific text inside it?

Comment: Yes, all the texts inside that element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

xpath that you should check :

```
//div[@class='show-more-less-html__markup']
```

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

If we have 1/1 matching node, Please make sure that :

1. This div is not under an iframe.
2. This div is not under a shadow-root.
3. You should not be on new tab/windows launched by selenium.

Once we are sure that we have unique entry and other criteria matches as well, we can try to extract text in the following way :

**Code trial 1 :**

```
try:
    msg = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='show-more-less-html__markup']"))).text
    print(msg)
except:
    pass
```

**Code trial 2 :**

```
try:
    msg = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='show-more-less-html__markup']"))).get_atrribute('innerHTML')
    print(msg)
except:
    pass
```

**Code trial 3 :**

```
try:
    msg = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='show-more-less-html__markup']"))).get_attribute('innerText')
    print(msg)
except:
    pass
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not Python

```
browser.findElement(By.className("description__text description__text--rich")).getText();
```

It's Java.
You are mixing things...